# My listView do marginRight in Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listView it viewed well in real device but it lets a space in right when I run it in Emulator

[image]

This is the code of my list in layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tipList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the code of the row item

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/tip_list_selector">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tip_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lieger jlgfi rehjglirejhgoljg rijgjre jgorejg jgjreo ijgoir gjro gjorjgo gjoirjgoirej gjogijrog joir oirjgojre"
    android:textColor="#4f4f4f"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favorite_star"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tips_star_off" />
```

**Hint:** The listView is inside a Fragment..

The activity_main code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/tip_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/header_logo" />


    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/actionBarBtns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_tip_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/header_search"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_tip_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/header_add"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/count_tip_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/count_tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/header_count" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:hint="Search Tips"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar" />

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />

 <!-- parts slider -->
<com.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/emy.dt4it.healthytips"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/left_layer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    slidingLayer:stickTo="left"
    slidingLayer:closeOnTapEnabled="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    slidingLayer:shadowWidth="@dimen/shadow_width"
    slidingLayer:offsetWidth="@dimen/offset_width">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/list_background">

        <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </com.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>

    <com.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/emy.dt4it.healthytips"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer2"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/right_layer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/tip_background">

    <include  layout="@layout/tip_details" android:id="@+id/include1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I opened it by the following code:

```
Fragment fragment = new TipsFragment(1,0, START_FROM);

if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);     
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

Comment: Where is each list bg image. May be bg image is small the screen size.

Comment: because you are giving in imageview xml:android:layout_marginRight="3dp"

Comment: I removed this line but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the layout of the row item with this one. This one should work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/tip_list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favorite_star"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tips_star_off" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tip_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/favorite_star"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lieger jlgfi rehjglirejhgoljg rijgjre jgorejg jgjreo ijgoir gjro gjorjgo gjoirjgoirej gjogijrog joir oirjgojre"
    android:textColor="#4f4f4f"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

The TextView will now be on the left of the ImageView, and match the remaining width.

Comment: Try replacing the tip_list_selector background with another image or a static color. For example, #ff0000.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are using fixed width for listview in your activity_main.xml.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

change 
`android:layout_width="220dp"` to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: This is not the listView that I use.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. The reason was image size, try to add imageView to this : `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: added it, still the same. :(